# [MapKit]implementing a delegate method

Tags: mapkit

the regionDidChangeAnimated is a delegate method which gets called instantaneously.
I want to set a BOLLEAN variable to NO when this method will be called, so i implement it :

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{

shouldAdjustZoom=NO;//this is the variable
}
```

am i right ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is called when the region has been changed, if you add a parameter, xcode will not find the method and will not enter it because it doesn't have the good name. 
I think so.